# Mapping composite poco to EF objectcontext entities

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have to produce an output from 3 separate tables(with a couple of fields from each table) into 1 output.  I have a class that represents that output.  The data is pulled from linq query of EF 6.1.x ObjectContext(Im stuck with using ObjectContext due to the nature of my clients needs....) entities (the 3 classes properly joined in the query) to a list of the new class (List<>).  I populate a grid and all is fine.  However the user wants to edit the data in the grid and now I need to push those new changes back.

My question is this:  Can I map my new class back to the entities field to field?  Or am I stuck with iterating through the collection and updating the tables individually?  I thought I could map but I haven't run across anything that substantiates this.

Comment: Would help to see what your classes look like.

Comment: I've never had a client asking for an `ObjectContext`... Anyway, please explain your issue by showing code.

Comment: @Gert - Client only wants a modification to their application, not a re-write.  To use DbContext would take a little more time and money that the client isn't willing to pay for.  So I have to use what I have in front of me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you not do this using the "Proxy" pattern?

I've done a 2 entity + Wrapper example pseudo example below.

EF would "Save" the SuperWrapper.DeptProxy and the SuperWrapper.EmpProxy.

```
public partial class DepartmentEFEntity    {
    public virtual Guid? DepartmentUUID { get; set; }

    public virtual string DepartmentName { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<EmployeeEFEntity> Employees { get; set; }

}



public partial class EmployeeEFEntity
{

    public virtual Guid? ParentDepartmentUUID { get; set; }

    public virtual Guid? EmployeeUUID { get; set; }

    public virtual DepartmentEFEntity ParentDepartment { get; set; }

    public virtual string SSN { get; set; }
}



public class SuperWrapper
{

    internal DepartmentEFEntity DeptProxy { get; private set; }
    internal EmployeeEFEntity EmpProxy { get; private set; }

    public SuperWrapper(DepartmentEFEntity dept, EmployeeEFEntity emp)
    {
        this.DeptProxy = dept;
        this.EmpProxy = emp;
    }

    public string DepartmentName
    {
        get { return null == this.DeptProxy ? string.Empty : this.DeptProxy.DepartmentName; }
        set { if(null!=this.DeptProxy{this.DeptProxy.DepartmentName =value;}}
    }

    public string EmployeeSSN
    {
        get { return null == this.EmpProxy ? string.Empty : this.EmpProxy.SSN; }
        set { if(null!=this.EmpProxy{this.EmpProxy.SSN =value;}}
    }

}
```

Comment: I will read up on this.  Not familiar with "Proxy" pattern with EF. Thx!

Comment: I don't think EF handles one-entity-split-amongst-several-tables very well.  NHibernate handles this better IIRC.  But that is sorta what you're asking (one-entity-multiple-tables).  So that is why the proxy idea came to mind.

Comment: yeah I had looked into the entity split and found that it was one to one so.... how would I map this back to EF? put the savechanges call in the superwrapper?

Comment: No, pass the superwrapper to your method "SaveMyEFStuff"....and use context to save both "properties" of the superwrapper.  it'll basically be something like context.SaveDeparement() and context.SaveEmployee()  (<<these methods don't exist, I'm giving you the idea, not the syntax-sugar)